# adding headers to pgfplotstable with color highlighting

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, colortbl

I have been trying for a long while now to put headers onto this:

[image]

I want to change the column headers from 0 to 10 into $O_{x}=0.0$ to $O_{x}=1.0$ but I can't seem to figure out how to do it. I have been going through the documentation and whenever I add a line all hell breaks loose. I have found a code snippet that I used to auto-color the text, so here is the code:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage[unskipbreak]{cuted}
\usepackage{caption}
\input{insbox}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.4}
\pgfplotsset{
    % this *defines* a custom colormap ...
    colormap={mycolor}{
        rgb255=(255,0,0)
        rgb255=(255,255,0)
        rgb255=(0,255,0)
    },
}


\pgfplotstableset{
    /color cells/min/.initial=0,
    /color cells/max/.initial=1000,
    /color cells/textcolor/.initial=,
    %
    % Usage: 'color cells={min=<value which is mapped to lowest color>, 
    %   max = <value which is mapped to largest>}
    color cells/.code=
    {%
        \pgfqkeys{/color cells}{#1}%
        \pgfkeysalso
        {%
            postproc cell content/.code=
            {%
                \begingroup
                \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@preprocessed cell content}\value
                \pgfmathfloatparsenumber{\value}%
                \pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfmathresult}%
                \let\value=\pgfmathresult
                \pgfplotscolormapaccess
                    [\pgfkeysvalueof{/color cells/min}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/color cells/max}]
                    {\value}
                    {\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/colormap name}}
                \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}\typesetvalue %This is the important if-statement for font color selection
                \ifdim\value pt<.5pt\relax
                  \def\textcolorvalue{black}%
                \else
                  \def\textcolorvalue{black}%
                \fi
                \toks0=\expandafter{\typesetvalue}%
                \xdef\temp{%
                    \noexpand\pgfkeysalso{%
                        @cell content={%
                            \noexpand\cellcolor[rgb]{\pgfmathresult}%
                            \noexpand\definecolor{mapped color}{rgb}{\pgfmathresult}%
                            \ifx\textcolorvalue\empty
                            \else
                                \noexpand\color{\textcolorvalue}%
                            \fi
                            \the\toks0 %
                        }%
                    }%
                }%
                \endgroup
                \temp
            }%
        }%
    }%
}


\makeatletter
\newcommand\fs@norules{\def\@fs@cfont{\bfseries}\let\@fs@capt\floatc@ruled
  \def\@fs@pre{}%
  \def\@fs@post{}%
  \def\@fs@mid{\kern3pt}%
  \let\@fs@iftopcapt\iftrue}
\makeatother

% \floatstyle{norules}
 \restylefloat{algorithm}

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}

\begin{strip}
    \centering\noindent
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    color cells={min=0,max=5,textcolor=-mapped color!50!black},
    /pgfplots/colormap name=mycolor,
    /pgf/number format/.cd,%sci,
    set decimal separator={.},
    every head row/.style={%
        output empty row,
        before row={%
            \toprule
            a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h & i & k\\
            },
        after row=\midrule,
        },
        every last row/.style={%
            after row=\bottomrule}
]
{
4.4744  2.3533  2.6725  2.7329  2.8773  4.2492  2.8385  2.6498  2.6023  2.3716  4.9849
4.3260  2.3847  2.9439  2.4219  2.0282  2.6892  1.9755  2.4186  2.9226  2.4088  4.8690
4.2227  2.3485  2.6576  2.0593  1.5806  2.2018  1.5116  2.0186  2.5371  2.3843  4.8027
4.1935  2.2956  2.3691  1.7961  1.2803  1.9126  1.1991  1.7263  2.2180  2.3466  4.8158
4.2310  2.2531  2.1729  1.5986  1.0466  1.7094  0.9544  1.5074  2.0058  2.3201  4.9024
4.3295  2.2297  2.0364  1.4407  0.8466  1.5532  0.7433  1.3311  1.8546  2.3134  5.0583
4.4896  2.2287  1.9398  1.3075  0.6626  1.4256  0.5471  1.1799  1.7416  2.3302  5.2866
4.7184  2.2525  1.8730  1.1897  0.4825  1.3166  0.3530  1.0429  1.6552  2.3735  5.5976
5.0305  2.3051  1.8312  1.0807  0.2959  1.2196  0.1497  0.9119  1.5894  2.4485  6.0109
5.4514  2.3931  1.8132  0.9747  0.0914  1.1295  -0.0754 0.7794  1.5410  2.5634  6.5593
6.0238  2.5285  1.8212  0.8657  -0.1461 1.0420  -0.3393 0.6373  1.5095  2.7323  7.2973

}

\captionof{figure}{The Battle of Fawzy}
\end{strip}

blablabla text

\section*{Appendix}
ererer this is an appendix and this is a sample paragraph in the sentence,m which is a very weird thing. Ah, now there is an indentation. That is just beautiful. 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're actually fairly close, your only problem is that you have `/pgf/number format/.cd,` before the `every head row` style. The `.cd` means that it sets `/pgf/number format` is set as the default path for the following keys, but `every head row` lives in `/pgfplots/table`. Move `every head row=/.style` before `/pgf/number format/.cd`.

If you put `$O(x)=0.0$` etc. in the first row though, the table becomes too wide though.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotsset{
    % this *defines* a custom colormap ...
    colormap={mycolor}{
        rgb255=(255,0,0)
        rgb255=(255,255,0)
        rgb255=(0,255,0)
    },
}


\pgfplotstableset{
    /color cells/min/.initial=0,
    /color cells/max/.initial=1000,
    /color cells/textcolor/.initial=,
    %
    % Usage: 'color cells={min=<value which is mapped to lowest color>, 
    %   max = <value which is mapped to largest>}
    color cells/.code=
    {%
        \pgfqkeys{/color cells}{#1}%
        \pgfkeysalso
        {%
            postproc cell content/.code=
            {%
                \begingroup
                \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@preprocessed cell content}\value
                \pgfmathfloatparsenumber{\value}%
                \pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfmathresult}%
                \let\value=\pgfmathresult
                \pgfplotscolormapaccess
                    [\pgfkeysvalueof{/color cells/min}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/color cells/max}]
                    {\value}
                    {\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/colormap name}}
                \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}\typesetvalue %This is the important if-statement for font color selection
                \ifdim\value pt<.5pt\relax
                  \def\textcolorvalue{black}%
                \else
                  \def\textcolorvalue{black}%
                \fi
                \toks0=\expandafter{\typesetvalue}%
                \xdef\temp{%
                    \noexpand\pgfkeysalso{%
                        @cell content={%
                            \noexpand\cellcolor[rgb]{\pgfmathresult}%
                            \noexpand\definecolor{mapped color}{rgb}{\pgfmathresult}%
                            \ifx\textcolorvalue\empty
                            \else
                                \noexpand\color{\textcolorvalue}%
                            \fi
                            \the\toks0 %
                        }%
                    }%
                }%
                \endgroup
                \temp
            }%
        }%
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    color cells={min=0,max=5,textcolor=-mapped color!50!black},
    /pgfplots/colormap name=mycolor,
    every head row/.style={%
        output empty row,
        before row={%
            a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h & i & k & l\\
            },
        },
    /pgf/number format/.cd,%sci,
    set decimal separator={.},
]
{
4.4744  2.3533  2.6725  2.7329  2.8773  4.2492  2.8385  2.6498  2.6023  2.3716  4.9849
4.3260  2.3847  2.9439  2.4219  2.0282  2.6892  1.9755  2.4186  2.9226  2.4088  4.8690
4.2227  2.3485  2.6576  2.0593  1.5806  2.2018  1.5116  2.0186  2.5371  2.3843  4.8027
4.1935  2.2956  2.3691  1.7961  1.2803  1.9126  1.1991  1.7263  2.2180  2.3466  4.8158
4.2310  2.2531  2.1729  1.5986  1.0466  1.7094  0.9544  1.5074  2.0058  2.3201  4.9024
4.3295  2.2297  2.0364  1.4407  0.8466  1.5532  0.7433  1.3311  1.8546  2.3134  5.0583
4.4896  2.2287  1.9398  1.3075  0.6626  1.4256  0.5471  1.1799  1.7416  2.3302  5.2866
4.7184  2.2525  1.8730  1.1897  0.4825  1.3166  0.3530  1.0429  1.6552  2.3735  5.5976
5.0305  2.3051  1.8312  1.0807  0.2959  1.2196  0.1497  0.9119  1.5894  2.4485  6.0109
5.4514  2.3931  1.8132  0.9747  0.0914  1.1295  -0.0754 0.7794  1.5410  2.5634  6.5593
6.0238  2.5285  1.8212  0.8657  -0.1461 1.0420  -0.3393 0.6373  1.5095  2.7323  7.2973

}

\end{document}
```